# как удалить элементы с recycleViewAdapter когда они достигают определенного числа

Tags: android, recyclerview, recyclerviewadapter

У меня есть адаптер и мне нужно будет удалить первый созданный элемент в этом адаптере как только число View элементов достигнет тридцати

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если у вас добавление происходит по одному элементу, то можно удалить так:

```
if(mList.size == 30){
    mList.removeAt(0)
    notifyItemRemoved(0)
}
```

либо полным пересозданием адаптера с подгрузкой массива без первого элемента. Проверку выше можно делать при добавлении элементов к массиву данных.

P.S. Пожалуйста прикладывайте код который у вас используется, так сложно помочь без знания ситуации в вашем коде.